# scala worksheet throwing error with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am trying run *spark* tests using *scala worksheet* in *Intellij*. But at the line of instantiation of `sparksession` or `sparkcontext`, the *worksheet* is throwing following error

> > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer
> >         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(scala tutorial.sc:377)
> >         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(scala tutorial.sc:420)
> >         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(scala tutorial.sc:327)
> >         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(scala tutorial.sc:353)
> >         at java.lang.Class.forName0(scala tutorial.sc)
> >         at java.lang.Class.forName(scala tutorial.sc:344)
> >         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(scala tutorial.sc:225)
> >         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.instantiateClass$1(scala tutorial.sc:256)
> >         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.instantiateClassFromConf$1(scala tutorial.sc:277)
> >         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(scala tutorial.sc:280)
> >         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(scala tutorial.sc:170)
> >         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(scala tutorial.sc:253)
> >         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(scala tutorial.sc:428)
> >         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(scala tutorial.sc:2316)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(scala tutorial.sc:827)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(scala tutorial.sc:819)
> >         at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(scala tutorial.sc:116)

I have tried unchecking the `Run worksheet in the compiler process` under `Worksheet` option of `Scala` setting which doesn't throw the error but doesn't even compile.

It is a maven project and following are the dependencies I have

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.holdenkarau/spark-testing-base_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.holdenkarau</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-testing-base_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0_0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Can somebody help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Unchecking the Run worksheet in the compiler process worked for me with the Intellij 2017.2.15

Comment: Thanks @ShankarKoirala  for the suggestion I tried that and didn't work 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow `Use external compile server for scala` option was unchecked which is under `Scala Compile Server` settings.

So in addition to following settings. [image]

I had to enable the following setting
[image]

I hope this would be helpful for everyone having the same problem as me.